# Asking for input again with do while loop in c

Tags: c, loops, do-while

I am trying to have the user type in a number between 1 and 8 to print out stuff on screen (height), if the number is lower than 1 or higher than 8 I would like for the program to prompt again for an input instead of it quitting out and say "invalid". I know I have to set it up with do on top and when on the bottom in C, my question is how would I go about it when I have 2 possible outcomes, i.e. too low or too high?

```
do {
    int height = get_int(Height: ");
    if (height < 1)
        ~ ~printf("invalid");
    else if (height > 8)
        ~ ~printf("invalid");
} when(???????) 

printf("valid")
```

Comment: Please format your code. You're also missing `;` at the end of all your statements.

Comment: apologies, its more psudo code so to speak, mainly to try and get the point across but I will of course use ; at the end of statements.

Answer (score 2):

The key is Logical OR operator (`||`) in [logical operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical).

A logical operator would :

1. treats its operands as boolean values

   - treats a non-zero value operand as `true`
   - treats a zero value operand as `false`
2. operates the boolean algebra on its operands
3. returns the boolean algebra result

   - returns `1` for true boolean result
   - returns `0` for false boolean result

The Logical OR operator (`||`) :

```
lhs || rhs
```

- Here, `lhs` and `rhs` are the 2 operands of OR(`||`) operator
- The OR operator returns `1` if any of the following conditions is true:

  1. only `lhs` is true
  2. only `rhs` is true
  3. both `lhs` and `rhs` are true
- In other words, the boolean algebra OR result is true if either `lhs` or `rhs` is true.

---

In your example, there are 2 conditions :

1. height is less than 1
2. height is larger than 8

if either of them is true, then the result is true (the loop will continue), so the expression in this example would be :

```c
int height; /* move height outside the loop so it can be used in do-while condition */
do {
    height = get_int();

    if (height < 1)
        printf("invalid\n");
    else if (height > 8)
        printf("invalid\n");
} while(height < 1 || height > 8);

printf("valid\n");
```

---

Furthermore, since we have already done the logical condition in the loop, we can just add a flag variable instead:

```c
int flag; /* record the boolean result */
do {
    int height = get_int();

    if (height < 1) {
        printf("invalid\n");
        flag = 1;
    } else if (height > 8) {
        printf("invalid\n");
        flag = 1;
    } else {
        flag = 0; /* !(height < 1 || height > 8) */
    }
} while(flag);

printf("valid\n");
```

Comment: You've been such a great help, I was trying && but didn't realize the logical error there, and then my problem was that I didn't "save" height outside the loop for while() to use it. changed those two things and bam! now its working! such a cool feeling. now to finish the 2/3 left of this project lol.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to see if it works for you. 
If not, leave a comment to tell me what you really want.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int height = 0;
    while (height < 1 || height > 8) {
        scanf("%d", &height);

        if (height >= 1 && height <= 8) {
            break;
        } else {
            printf("Invalid, please try again.\n");
        }
    }

    printf("Valid.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of checking if the user has made an invalid choice would be to use a simple Boolean variable and set it to "false" when an invalid choice is made.

I have modified your own example code to include what I mean here:

```
bool valid = true;
do {
  valid = true; //reset valid to true at the beginning of the loop, otherwise it will remain false when the loop runs again
  int height = get_int("Height: ");
  if (height < 1)
    valid = false; //set valid to false when an invalid choice is made
  else if (height > 8)
    valid = false; //set valid to false when an invalid choice is made
} while (!valid) //if valid is not true ( or ==false), repeat. If valid is true or not equal to false, don't repeat and continue to the print statement below. 

print("valid");
```

Please note that I used the same `get_int` function you provided in your post. I am not aware of this function. For ways of reading integers (for example `scanf`) see other answers in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
        
int main() { 
    int num;
    do {
        printf("Enter 0 to quit\n");
        printf("Print Enter number between 1 and 8\n");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        if (num > 8) {
            printf("Number to high\n");
        } else if (num < 0) {
            printf("Number to low\n");
        }

        if (num == 0) {
            printf("You quit the program goodby\n");
        } else {
            printf("Number within range\n");
        }
    } while(num != -0);

    return 0;
}
```